# Work with decimal values after avro deserialization

Tags: decimal, avro

I take AVRO bytes from Kafka and deserialize them.
But I get strange output because of decimal value and I cannot work with them next (for example turn into json or insert into DB):

```
import avro.schema, json
from avro.io import DatumReader, BinaryDecoder
# only needed part of schemaDict
schemaDict = {
  
      "name": "ApplicationEvent",
      "type": "record",
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "desiredCreditLimit",
          "type": [
            "null",
            {
              "type": "bytes",
              "logicalType": "decimal",
              "precision": 14,
              "scale": 2
            }
          ],
          "default": null
        }
      ]
    }
schema_avro = avro.schema.parse(json.dumps(schemaDict))
reader = DatumReader(schema_avro_io)
decoder = BinaryDecoder(data) #data - bynary data from kafka
event_dict = reader.read(decoder)
print (event_dict)
#{'desiredCreditLimit': Decimal('100000.00')}
print (json.dumps(event_dict))
#TypeError: Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable
```

I tried to use avro_json_serializer, but got error: **"AttributeError: 'decimal.Decimal' object has no attribute 'decode'"**.
And because of this "Decimal" in dictionary I cannot insert values to DB too.
Also tried to use `fastavro` library, but I couldnot deserealize message, as I understand because sereliazation done without `fastavro`.

Comment: I found workaround with:

`from decimal import Decimal
def my_default(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, Decimal):
        return float(obj)
    return str(obj)

json_data = json.dumps(event_dict, ensure_ascii=False, default=my_default)
print(json_data)`

But maybe there is more flexible solution? I expect completely different type of avro data anf don't wont to write for each unusual type spesial function.